# SeriLog: How to compress rotated file logs and delete older compressed logs?

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

I want to compress the rotated logs, and if the number of rotated logs exceeds the limit, delete the old ones. Already checked the [serilog-sinks-file-archive](https://github.com/cocowalla/serilog-sinks-file-archive). It does a great job of compressing, but it doesn't delete previous files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appreciate this is an old post so hoping you've solved the challenge by now. You didn't share any detail on what you've tried but in the interest of helping you if you don't already have a solution...

You can implement two simple methods:

1. `SerilogHousekeeping` the entry point that gathers all files in the target directory

```
public void SerilogHousekeeping(string filePath, string searchPattern, bool includeSubDirectories, int retentionPeriod)
{
    if (!includeSubDirectories)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, searchPattern).ToList();
        CheckAndDeleteFiles(files, retentionPeriod);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(filePath))
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(subDirectory, searchPattern).ToList(); 
            CheckAndDeleteFiles(files, retentionPeriod);   
        }
    }
}
```

2. `CheckAndDeleteFiles` that checks if a given file is outside the retention period and, if so, attempts to delete it

```
private void CheckAndDeleteFiles(List<string> files, int retentionPeriod)
{
    foreach (var filename in files)
    {
        if (DateTime.UtcNow - File.GetCreationTimeUtc(filename) >= TimeSpan.FromDays(retentionPeriod))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(filename);
            }
            catch ()
            {
                // Handle your exception here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Call `SerilogHousekeeping()` at whatever place is appropriate for your application (e.g. before you configure `Serilog.Log.Logger` in your startup). For example, to remove all `.txt` files that are over 60 days old in the relative `Logs` directory (not recursive) then call:

```
SerilogHousekeeping(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"Logs"), "*.txt", false, 60)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hope this will help future readers. I also used similar technique but then we have switch to another log provider.